# SQL Server CLR UDF with Out Parameters - Is It Possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

Is there a way to create a CLR User-Defined Function for SQL Server which returns multiple values **without using Table Valued Function** syntax?  For example, say I want to perform a coordinate conversion such as:

```
[SqlFunction()]
public void ConvertCoordinates(SqlDouble x, SqlDouble y, SqlDouble z, out SqlDouble r, out SqlDouble t, out SqlDouble p)
{
   r = new SqlDouble(Math.Sqrt((x.Value*x.Value)+(y.Value*y.Value)+(z.Value*z.Value)));
   t = new SqlDouble(Math.Acos(r.Value / z.Value));
   p = new SqlDouble(Math.Atan(y.Value / x.Value));
}
```

Is this even possible?  A table-valued function in this case seems inappropriate because the computation will never yield more than one output row.  Using scalar valued function syntax, I would have to write three different functions to perform the computation and call each separately.  Given my actual use case, this is highly impractical.

I realize that the above logic can be accomplished using pure T-SQL; my actual use case is more complex but would still only result in a single row having multiple interdependent output values.

So, bottom line, is it feasible?  I don't think it is, but one can hope.  If by chance it is feasible, then what would the T-SQL look like that calls such a function?

Comment: UDFs (whether Scalar, or Tabular, T-SQL or CLR) cannot have out parameters. If they could, you'd have to invent new syntax to allow one to be called in the `SELECT` clause, if you wanted to consume these outputs. And I don't see why a table-valued function returning a single row should seem strange to you.

Comment: @Damien This was simply a question of whether or not it's possible.  My own reading and experimentation had indicated it probably wasn't (as I also stated), but since I'm new to CLR integration I wanted to ask.  TVFs don't seem "strange to me" when more than 1 row is a possibility.  The example ALWAYS returns a single row, yet the interrelated return values are only meaningful as a set.  In my actual use case I'm performing a similar, but larger computation for millions of rows, so a TVF just seems inefficient if out parameters were a possibility. A simple 'no' would have been sufficient.

Comment: @bporter - obviously a TVF would be the best option - you say it yourself, they "don't seem strange when more than 1 row is a possibility" and then say you have millions of rows. Ergo a (S)TVF is the answer! Its going to be way more efficient than iterating over every row like an imperative foreach statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've already taken the CLR plunge, you could create your own CLR type with which you can do all sorts of crazy stuff. As a practical example, the native spatial types are implemented this way, as is HierarchyID. Once you've defined your own type, you can have your function return it. If getting at individual components (if I may presume in your case radius, theta, and phi), create methods on the type that return such.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  UDTs would make this much simpler, and I did look into them.  The only concern I had was that I have to register the assembly with every database.  In my case, I'm mining data from hundreds of databases accumulated over the past 10 years or so.  UDFs seemed simpler because I could place them in one database and call them from the other databases to perform computations.  Is there a way that you know of to make UDTs available across all databases similar to the spatial types (without registering the assembly with each database)?

Comment: I can think of a couple of approaches. The first is if you just register it once in one db and do all your data collection in that db's context. The other would be to deploy it everywhere. Since it's T-SQL and you presumably already have a way to run code against every db, this shouldn't be an issue. Keep in mind that you can deploy assemblies through a bitstream right in the script rather than having to deploy the DLL everywhere and reference that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question and I found it while searching for an answer to a very similar question.

SQL Functions allow for a return value but do not allow the use of an output parameter.

SQL Procedures do allow output parameters (but not a return value)

I found this from the MSDN Example here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

```
 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
 public static void PriceSum(out SqlInt32 value)
 { … }
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PriceSum (@sum int OUTPUT)
AS EXTERNAL NAME TestStoredProc.StoredProcedures.PriceSum
```

When I switched from trying to register a Function to a Procedure everything worked out. It should be pointed out that a Function can have a return value but a Stored Procedure can not. In my case I was returning a string value and had output params for some optional detailed information like status codes, etc. All I did was change my method to be a void and passed the string value back as an output param.

Your method is a void anyways and has no return value and as such is a perfect candidate for using a Stored Procedure instead of a Function.

Answer (score -1):

I admit I have not tried it, but I imagine the T-SQL would like,

```
DECLARE @X FLOAT(53),
        @Y FLOAT(53),
        @Z FLOAT(53),
        @R FLOAT(53),
        @T FLOAT(53),
        @P FLOAT(53)

EXEC    ConvertCoordinates
        @X = 0,
        @Y = 0,
        @Z = 0,
        @R = @R OUTPUT,
        @T = @T OUTPUT
        @P = @P OUTPUT
```